# Hyperparameter Tuning with Keras Tuner RandomSearch Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-tuner

I am using keras tuner to optimize hyperparameters: hidden layers, neurons, activation function, and learning rate. I have time series regression problem with 31 inputs, 32 outputs with N number of data samples.

My original X_train shape is (N,31) and Y_train shape is (N,32). I transform it to work for keras shape and I reshape X_train and Y_train as following:
X_train.shape: (N,31,1)
Y_train.shape: (N,32).

[image: Code]

In the above code, X_train.shape(1) is 31 and Y_train.shape(1) is 32. When I used hyperparameter tuning, it says ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 20).

Following Error exists:
[image]

What I am missing and what is its issues.

Answer (score 0):

LSTM layers expects a 3D tensor input with the shape [batch, timesteps, feature]. Since you are using number of layers are a tuning parameter along with LSTM layers, when the number of LSTM layers is 2 and above, the LSTM layers after the first LSTM layer will also expect a 3D tensor as input which means that you will need to add the 'return_sequences=True' parameter to the setup so that the output tensor from previous LSTM layer has ndim=3 (i.e. batch size, timesteps, hidden state) which is fed into the next LSTM layer.

Comment: I have added return_sequences=True. Still, there are issues:  ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 31 and 192 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential/dense/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [192,31,32], [192,32].
tuner.results_su